# Java Application - Getting Text of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield, joptionpane

I have two classes on my application, the main one and other for the interface. Using netbeans i created some fields, including JTextFields.

Now, what i pretend is to do an insert on the embedded database using this method of the main class:

```
try {
        stmtSaveNewRecord = dbConnection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO APP.Alunos " +
    "   (FIRSTNAME, AGE) " +
    "VALUES (?, ?)",
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Aquitex.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

int id = -1;
try {
    stmtSaveNewRecord.clearParameters();
    stmtSaveNewRecord.setString(1, da.getjTextField1());
    stmtSaveNewRecord.setInt(2, da.getjTextField2());
    int rowCount = stmtSaveNewRecord.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet results = stmtSaveNewRecord.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (results.next()) {
        id = results.getInt(1);
    }
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
    sqle.printStackTrace();
}
return id;
```

As you can see, i call two methods i created on the interface class (getjTextField1 and getjTextField2).

```
public String getjTextField1(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jTextField1.getText());
    return jTextField1.getText();

}
```

The problem is i can't get the value inputed on the jFieldTexts. As you can see in the code above, i even call JOptionPane to see what it returns after i input some data on the jTextField1 but is always null.

Comment: you should post your entire code to figure out where the problem is

Comment: Sidenote: do not mix database queries/access with Swing code. Swing code belongs on the Event Dispatch Thread, database code not. See the [Swing concurrency guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Definitely not enough information to answer your question... Show us the creation/implementation of the field 'da'. Where/when is the db code being executed? (as mentioned above mixing db access with swing has some caveats)

Comment: I'm looking at your link Robin, but i'm having some difficult to understand :/

The problem never reaches the main class since even in the interface methos the getText() is always null. I don't have much more code to show since the interface was built throught the java interface panel on netbeans. I just created the getjTextField1() to try to get the text, didn't do much more on the interface class.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @wxyz  *"you should post your entire code"*  You are prepared to look through 2000 LOC over 16 classes (just WAGing)?  Better to boil the problem down to an SSCCE.

Comment: If that first code block is accurately portrayed as a single block, there should only be one try/catch.  If the first block fails, `stmtSaveNewRecord` will likely be `null`.  Also, call `e.printStackTrace()` in any catch & copy/paste the output as an edit to the question.  I doubt anyone will be able to solve this just from the code snippets shown above.

Comment: Also note that @Robin will not be informed of a new comment unless there is the '@PersonName' in the reply.

Comment: Make sure that `jTextField1` is only declared once and hasn't being re-declared within the ui creation code